# smarty shows variable only if debug is acitve

Tags: php, codeigniter, debugging, smarty

I have the following smarty template:

```
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-sm-offset-4 login-box">
{$validation_errors}
    <p class="heading">Please Log In!</p>
    {form url='user/login'}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Email">Email address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Password">Email address</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password" placeholder="Enter password" name="password" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Submit</button>
    {form}
</div>
```

This is the PHP Code to assign `$validation_errors`:

```
$this->smartyci->assign('validation_errors', $error);
```

So my problem now is, that `$validation_errors` is only shown in the template if I set smarty to debug mode like this:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-offset-4 col-sm-offset-4 login-box">
{debug}
{$validation_errors}
    <p class="heading">Please Log In!</p>
    {form url='user/login'}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Email">Email address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Password">Email address</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password" placeholder="Enter password" name="password" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Submit</button>
    {form}
</div>
```

I have really now idea why the variable is only shown when I put {debug} in the template. Btw any other variables are working fine.

Comment: $this->smartyci->assign('validation_errors', $error); - is it mistake with $this-smartyci ???

Comment: No $this->smartyci is fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Somehow the $validation_errors variable was effected by smarty caching.
I've disabled chaching, and everything works fine now.